# What is the best way to handle listing multiple questions?

Tags: forms, lists, input-fields, input

I'm working on a form where a user is asked to list various questions. My initial design looks like this:

[image: imag]

Users can enter multiple questions separated by line breaks. My worry with this interaction is that there's a lot of room for error. For example, one question could have multiple lines. Or a user may forget to use line breaks and just write a paragraph of questions.

Another approach I decided to try was this:

[image: image2]

Every time a user wants to add a new question, they have to click the "Add another question" button. I'm leaning towards this approach since there's less room for error, however it is more work having click the button and into a new text field.

What do you guys think? Is the second approach is the way to go? Is there another way to tackle this?

Comment: The text "Add another question" confuses me. Does it mean that I am adding the current question or that another input field will appear where I can add a different question? If it is the first, I'd recommend just writing "Add" in the button and placing it next to the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option creates a clearer visual distinction between questions, and reduces the margin for error.

Entering a question will involve, say, 40 key presses. So, relatively, a single additional click won't constitute a massive increase in physical load. Especially if users can <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the button then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If the click really bothers you, as soon as the user starts typing a question you can automatically add a field for the succeeding question.

Comment: Better yet, it could be programmed to respond to the enter button without having to press tab ;)

Comment: @Winter That will only work if a question cannot have more than one line (input vs text area).

Comment: Actually you can program a textarea to respond to a keypress in that way, but it might not be so intuitive. My comment was based on the assumption that you were recommending the second option.